# how to use ngkey-up for jquery function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here I have a jquery function for keyup,I have four div's with class name,I have to give keyup function for four divs,so I used jquery function.But I need In angularjs.

JS:

```
 $(".entrcde").keyup(function () {
    var fill = true;
    $(".entrcde").each(function (i, e) {
        if ($(e).val() == "")
            fill = false;
    });
    if (fill) {
        window.location.href = "/login.html";
    }
    //focus next elements
    var tabindex = $(this).attr("tabindex");
    tabindex++;
    $('input[tabindex=' + (tabindex) + ']').focus();
});
```

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" maxlength="1" tabindex="1" class="entrcde" />
                <input type="text" maxlength="1" tabindex="2" class="entrcde" />
                <input type="text" maxlength="1" tabindex="3" class="entrcde" />
                <input type="text" maxlength="1" tabindex="4" class="entrcde" />
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Please help me how to do with angular by using ngkey-up or any custom directive.

Comment: use `ng-keyup` directive

Comment: Have you read/tried anything with angular as per your requirements ? What did not work ?

Comment: @Rayon I read but I did not understand,how to do with four div(i.e; four input boxes is filled it must be return true).

Comment: on every input write ng-keyup or ng-keydown event and do what you need to do. <input type="text"............. ng-keydown="alert("div1")" />

Comment: @geminiousgoel  I tried but is not working

Comment: do provide fiddle.

Comment: @geminiousgoel https://plnkr.co/edit/FdlmBuDoYs1LiqwvFXhu?p=preview

Comment: @pbsbr  Had you included the ng-app directive and controller in application. If no, then Man do read the basics of angular first. You are missing that. Function cannot be called as such.

Comment: @geminiousgoel I included,I will update the plunker

Answer (score 0):

```
function keyupevent() {
var fill = true;
$(".entrcde").each(function (i, e) {
    if ($(e).val() == "")
        fill = false;
});
if (fill) {
    window.location.href = "/login.html";
}
//focus next elements
var tabindex = $(this).attr("tabindex");
tabindex++;
$('input[tabindex=' + (tabindex) + ']').focus();
}
```

use this function for your keyup event

and in your html

```
     <input type="text" ng-keyup="keyupevent()" maxlength="1" tabindex="1" 
  class="entrcde" />
```

Comment: Sorry,I need in angular